# From Arduino and breadboard to PCB

Tags: pcb-design

After building a working prototype with a breadboard, I was wondering what's next.
So I read about integrating the arduino into a PCB layout.

But in my case, it's worth it?

My project will use a Arduino Mega, futhermore some wired piezo switches therefore I need pcb connectors, and a small amount of resistor and transistors. 
I am considering to buy a Mega of the shelf and use the contactpins on a header to fix it on my PCB. Also probably fix it with some screws.

It will save me a lot of pcb design time (a maybe some mistakes) and it will save me buying all diferent components. The  ATMega2560 alone is already around 10,-

I think I only need 10 or 15 pcb's, definitly no massproduction.

Your opinions...

Comment: Well, in my last job we're using own arduino mega clone with micromatch connectors (much more reliable than the original ones). But we didn't want to integrate it, it's easier to swap or test it (without that 300mm x 250mm board with relays, optotriacs, power supplies and many more.

Comment: Maybe a simple Prototyping Shield would be sufficient for you.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Majenko's proposal for a proto shield, or 
if you need a "flat" design beside the Mega get yourself a striped (one /two sided and in different sizes) vero board (its like a breadboard to solder)

[image]

You could even use Fritzing to design the most efficient layout for this option in regards to space/material saving or minimum solder points

Comment: Big fan of Veroboard - to add I have used VeroDes (https://heyrick.eu/software/verodes/) which is a free CAD tool for Veroboard design!